# XL-Deploy: How to retrieve information about an Exection Plan Step?

Tags: rest, deployit, xl-deploy

In [TaskBlockService](https://docs.xebialabs.com/generated/xl-deploy/5.5.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.TaskBlockService.html) there is a `GET` call *retrieves information about a step* given `/tasks/v2/{taskid}/step/{stepPath}`.

**Question** How to specify the value for the *stepPath* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets see what blocks do we have inside a given task.

Lets suppose, `b9f5b44c-1754-4689-9129-e79376268d21` is the Task ID.
Below is the REST call. Change `localhost:4516` to your own XLD Host:Port.

http://localhost:4516/deployit/tasks/v2/b9f5b44c-1754-4689-9129-e79376268d21/

It will return details about this very task. I am only pasting the relevant part i.e. list of blocks within this task.

```
<block id="0" state="FAILED" description="" hasSteps="true" root="true">
        <block id="0_1" state="FAILED" description="Deploy" hasSteps="true" phase="true">
            <block id="0_1_1" state="FAILED" description="Deploy MySQL 1.0 on MySQL" hasSteps="true"/></block>
        <block id="0_2" state="PENDING" description="" hasSteps="true" phase="true">
            <block id="0_2_1" state="PENDING" description="Register changes for MySQL" hasSteps="true"/></block>
    </block>
```

**Block ID 0** means parent block. Inside it, we can see there are multiple child blocks viz. **0_1** & **0_2**. And within these child blocks, there are 2 steps viz. **0_1_1** & **0_1_2**.

So, in order to see details about these steps, prefix `step/0_1_1_1` to above REST call.

Please note above that I specified **0_1_1_1** which is a `stepPath` inside **0_1_1**. It gives output similar to below.

```
<step failures="0" state="DONE">
    <description>Run 01-CreateTable.sql on MySQLClient</description>
    <startDate>2017-04-26T05:26:30.044+0000</startDate>
    <completionDate>2017-04-26T05:26:32.568+0000</completionDate>
    <log>Uploading artifact [/tmp/ot-20170426T072630452.1/Archive.zip]
 </step>
```

Similarly, If I replace `step/0_1_1_1` with `step/0_1_1_2` in above REST call, I can see details of other `stepPath` i.e. `0_1_1_2`.

```
<step failures="1" state="FAILED">
    <description>Run 02-CreateUser.sql on MySQLClient</description>
    <startDate>2017-04-26T05:26:32.618+0000</startDate>
    <completionDate>2017-04-26T05:26:34.424+0000</completionDate>
    <log>Uploading artifact [/tmp/ot-20170426T072632621.1/Archive.zip]
</step>
```

I hope, this clarifies how to specify value for `stepPath` in XL Deploy.

Answer (score 1):

The approach would be to first get the task blocks:

```
curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:4516/deployit/tasks/v2/28830810-5104-4ab9-9826-22f66dee265d
```

From there you can use the block id to list the steps for a particular block:

```
curl -uadmin:password http://local6/deployit/tasks/v2/28830810-5104-4ab9-9826-22f66dee265d/block/0_1_1/step
```

There the steps will be listed and you can use the order of that list to deduce the step path, i.e. the steps are numbered within the block starting from 1.

So the first step in block 0_1_1 has path 0_1_1_1.